# How do I get burnt villages back to good condition?

Tags: mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword

I had to go to the village Nesvisz to continue the quest of THE SECRET OF BLACK MACE but when I went there I found that village has been plundered.  How do I restore the village so I can continue the quest?

Comment: What? That's pretty unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for about 2 weeks (ingame time) for a village to restore again.